# Irregular shapes Zone in PDF

Tags: pdf, trim

Is there a way to crop polygon (irregular shapes) zones in PDF using GhostSCript.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot use Ghostscript to do that.

But yes, principally you can do that in PDFs. The concept then is not called "trim" or "crop" but "clip". Clipping is a basic concept of the PostScript and the PDF graphic models.

There are related "operators" for clipping any graphic object in either page description language. Search for "PLRM.pdf" and for "PDF3200_2008.pdf" on the Adobe websites. They contain the official specifications for the two formats.

Then, for both languages/formats lookup the operators for "clipping path":

1. `W` and `W*` for PDF
2. `clippath`, `clip` and other keywords containing 'clip' for PostScript

If you want to clip irregular shapes from complete pages of existing PDFs, you have to create an additional PDF page which constructs an opaque area that has the irregular "hole" clipped into it. Then overlay the new page to the old one.